# Deleting contents of file after success

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I want to run the same Powershell command for every OU.
The list of OUs is given in a text file.

```
**Powershell command:**
run_script OU1
run_script OU2

**Text File:**
OU1
OU2
...
```

So far I have written the following logic:

```
$OUnames = Get-Content("C:\ouNames.txt");
foreach ($OU in $OUnames)
{
    $output = run_script $OU
      if($output -contains "success")
      // then delete $OU from ouNames.txt
      // and inlcude $OU in the file ouNamesAdded.txt
}
```

How to delete the `OU` from the first text file after the `run_script $OU` returns `success` for a particular `OU`. Also, how to add `$OU` to another file `ouNamesAdded.txt`

How can I pickup multiple `OU` from the `C:\ouNames.txt` and then run `run_script $OU` in parallel for multiple OUs

Comment: It is **very** unclear what the `run_script` is doing with the parameter `$OU`. Especially, since this seems to contain just the Name, not the DistinghuishedName.. Please explain a bit more and show us the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

For adding new OU content to a new file, you can use `Add-Content`:

```
$OU | Add-Content "ouNamesAdded.txt"
```

For removing content, I would just do that after you finish the loop. You can remove the `-whatif` parameter if you are happy with the command.

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content ouNames.txt) -DifferenceObject (Get-Content ouNamesAdded.txt) -PassThru | Set-Content ouNames.txt -whatif
```

I don't know of anything that will just delete a line from a file. If you want to delete an OU from the file after every iteration, you will need to do something like the following:

```
# Execute within the if statement
Get-Content ouNames.txt -notmatch "^$OU$" | Set-Content ouNames.txt
# Or using the $OUNames array (more efficient)
$OUnames -notmatch "^$OU$" | Set-Content ouNames.txt
```

If you want to track a list and do real-time deletions, I would use something like an arraylist:

```
# Run this before the loop code
$OUs = $OUnames.clone() -as [system.collections.arraylist]
# Run this within the if statement
$OUs.Remove($OU)
# After the loop completes, then write to the output file
$OUs | Set-Content "ouNamesAdded.txt"
```

Comment: How can I pickup multiple OU from the C:\ouNames.txt and then run run_script $OU in parallel for multiple OUs

Comment: I would look at [PowerShell Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-6) for parallel execution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I cooked up:

```
    $OUnames = Get-Content("C:\ouNames.txt")
foreach ($OU in $OUnames)
{
$output = run_script $OU
  if($output -contains "success")
  {
   $OUs = Get-Content("C:\ouNames.txt")
   $OUs -notmatch "$OU" | Out-File "C:\ouNames.txt"
   $OU | Out-File "C:\ouNamesAdded.txt" -Append
  }
}
```

This code will go through the text file and run the "run_script' command on each of them. If successful, it will grab all the text in the file that doesn't match the successful OU, and write that to the text file, effectively erasing the string that ran successfully. It'll then write the successful string to a new "ouNamesAdded' text file.

Comment: How can I pickup multiple `OU` from the `C:\ouNames.txt` and then run `run_script $OU` in parallel for multiple OUs

Comment: @meallhour That's more complicated than it seems and I don't have experience in it. You'd probably be best off leaving it as a loop.